# Is it possible to create a 'button' on Google Docs user interface using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible add a custom button like 'submit for review' into google docs UI, while integrating google docs into our use case?

I see apps script allows us to create custom menus: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

What I'd essentially want to do is, add a button similar to or replace the share button in google docs Ui with our own custom button.

Comment: You have asked two questions. Can I a) "add a custom button like 'submit for review' into google docs UI"? and b) replace the share button in google docs Ui with our own custom button? It does not follow that the answer to the first question is the answer to the second question. Which of the two do you really want answered?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, corrected